# calculating sum of ListRelation range

Tags: sum, range, rascal

I have a ListRelation called PLOCs of type:

```
lrel[loc, int] PLOCs = [<a, calcPLOC(a)> | a <- files];
```

where files is a set of locations, and calcPLOC calculates an integer based on that location.

Now I want the sum of all the calculated integers. I used 3 different ways to calculate this, and got 2 different answers:

1:

```
total = 0;
for (<a, b> <- PLOCs) { 
    total += b;
}
println("total PLOC: <total>"); // returns 23805
```

2:

```
total = sum(range(PLOCs));
println("total PLOC: <total>"); // returns 21313
```

3:

```
total = (0 | it + b | <a, b> <- PLOCs);
println("total PLOC: <total>"); // returns 23805
```

Why does the second method return a different result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range function from ListRelation "squeezes" out duplicate entries, but keeps their order.

Comment: This should be part of the documentation, because the current text is misleading: "The range (i.e., all but the first element of each tuple) of a list relation."

Comment: Yes. See https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/issues/1296 ; just added